# Maintaining connections with many real-time devices

Tags: c, sockets, udp, real-time

I'm writing a program on Linux to control about 1000 Patient Monitors at same time over UDP sockets. I've successfully written a library to parse and send messages to collect the data from a single patient monitor device. There are various scheduling constraints on the the device, listed below:-

- Each device must constantly get an alive-request from computer client within max time-period of 300 milliseconds(may differ for different devices), otherwise connection is lost.
- Computer client must send a poll-request to a device in order fetch the data within some time period. I'm polling for about 5 seconds of averaged data from patient monitor, therefore, I'm required to send poll-request in every 5 * 3 = 15 seconds. If I fail to send the request within 15 seconds time-frame, I looses the connection from device.

Now, I'm trying to extend my current program so that it is capable of handling about 1000+ devices at same time. Right now, my program can efficiently handle and parse response from just one device. In case of handling multiple devices, it is necessary to synchronize multiple responses from different device and serialize them and stream it over TCP socket, so that remote computers can also analyze the data. Well, that is not a problem because it is a well know multiple-producer and single consumer problem. My main concern is, what approach should I use in order to maintain alive-connection 1000+ devices.

After reading over Internet and browsing for similar questions on this website, I'm mainly considering two options:-

- Use one thread per device. In order to control 1000+ device, I would end up in making 1000+ threads which does not look feasible to me.
- Use multiplexing approach, selecting FD that requires attention and deal with it one at a time. I'm not sure how would I go about it and if multiplexing approach would be able to maintain alive-connection with all the devices considering above two constants.

I need some suggestions and advice on how to deal with this situation where you need to control 1000+ real-time-device over UDP sockets. Each device requires some alive-signal every 300 milliseconds (differ for different devices) and they require poll request in about 3 times the time interval mentioned during association phase. For example, patient monitors in ICU may require real-time (1 second averaged) data where as patient monitors in general wards may require 10-seconds averaged data, therefore, poll period for two devices would be 3*1(3 seconds) and 3*10 (30 seconds) respectively.

Thanks
Shivam Kalra

Comment: I'm not sure if Windows have anything better or more effective than `select`/`poll` but it should have. On Linux you can use e.g. [`epoll`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll), and BSD systems have similar methods.

Comment: @User-104 : can help me in this question. i think you got solved based on your this question: tinyurl.com/jnoekwf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the most part either approach is at least functionally capable of handling the functionality you describe, but by the sounds of things performance will be a crucial issue.  From the figures you have provided it seems that the application could be CPU-buond.

A multithreaded approach has the advantage of using all of the available CPU cores on the machine, but multithreaded programs are notorious for being difficult to make reliable and robust.

You could also use the Apache's old tried-and-true forked-worker model - create, say, a separate process to handle a maximum of 100 devices.  You could then need to write code to manage the mapping of connections to processes.

You could also use multiple *hosts* and some mechanism to distribute devices among them.  This would have the advantage of making it easier to handle recovery situations.  It sounds like your application could well be mission critical, and it may need to be architected so that if any one piece of hardware breaks then other hardware will take over automatically.